# Docker windows 10 with gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab

Good afternoon,

I have a doubt.

My Operating System is Windows 10, I have docker installed on it and would like to by the ubuntu with gitlab.

It is possible? I tried to do this but I had a problem communicating. I have seen in some places that it does not have support.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 with docker, you can start the [omnibus](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/) gitlab version.

Pull the [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) and run it with these arguments :

```
docker run --detach --hostname HOSTNAME --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --name gitlab --restart always gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to access gitlab through my localhost, but not through the page I set up. Do you know why?

Comment: You should be able to access the gitlab through the name defined after `--hostname` flag using http or https

Comment: Make sure the ports are not being blocked in the firewall